# my server not loading due to exceeding of execution time due to infinte loop in the code

Tags: php, laravel, admin

i am building a project in laravel 5.3,i was working on user roles,and when i had finished all the coding,i wasn't able to start my server,everytime i run the command `php artisan serve` the laptops hangs within seconds and i have to restart it.since `php artisan serve` does not work i used `php -S localhost:8000 -t` it didn't hang but the project at 127.0.0.1 still does not work.

the error terminal shows is

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 549

i have never worked with this file `container.php`, i don't understand the reason for the error.maybe there is an infinite loop in my code.

my code for `auth.php` where i made all the changes is

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin'=> [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin-api'=> [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],



],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 15,
    ],

];
```

this is the function of `container.php`

```
foreach ($this->abstractAliases[$abstract] as $alias) {
        if (! is_null($binding = $this->findInContextualBindings($alias))) {
            return $binding;
        }
}
```

i have no understanding of this function and what it is calling.but according to my terminal this is exceeding the execution time of 30 seconds.

Comment: i already have changed default time from 3o to 300 seconds and it still does not work,so i am pretty sure there ia an infinite loop in the code.

Comment: Changing timeout seconds is the absolutely wrong suggestion and workaround. You're in a forever loop in your `foreach`. I'll submit an answer.

Comment: matter of fact is that i have never messed with this file,container.php and till yesterday my server was working fine.i started to work upon multi role users ,made migration,created controller,routes ,views and changed auth.php and it started happening.

Comment: If `php artisan serve` is not working....umm...you have a much bigger problem. Rollback your source, if you can. Slowly add re-add code and test. Open VirtualBox or whatever you use and hard close/restart, etc.